# Toggle function on strings

Tags: java, php

I am not sure if this is possible, but it is possible to toggle a string? I have a string that echo's out of a DB. And i wanted to toggle the sting as all the products the string reads out is enormous, in order for the page to be more user friendly.

```
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX); //overrid a common php nonsense error
    $fc_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Food_Cat");
    $fc_sel->data_seek(0);

    echo("<br>");
    echo("<button onclick='toggle_visibility('forms')'>Hello!</button>");
    echo("<div class='forms'>");

    while ($output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fc_run .= $output['Food_Cat_name'] . $output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $output['Food_Cat_name']; //echo out product name
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $output['Food_Cat_Desc']; //echo out product desc
    // echo out all add on's and delete button
    echo("<div id='header'>");
    echo(" <p id='session'>" . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </p>");
    echo("</br>");
    echo("<input type='button' id='submit_addon' name='submit_addon' onclick='toggle_visibility('forms')'>");
    echo("</div>");
```

Javascript

```
 //turn entire div into toggle
 function toggle_visibility(id) {
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
         e.style.display = 'none';
     else
         e.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

I have tested what i am using on HTML and its works perfectly. But does not work in the string.
Any suggestions.

Comment: you should replace "Java" with "javascript" in your post otherwise some people will go nuts ;).

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle a string"? The JavaScript code you posted should work for toggling the visibility of an element.

Comment: @JoeAttardi yeah that is what i thought. It works on HTML, but any information which has been echo'd out it does not seem to work on and i don't see why not

Comment: @monroe look into the source in your browser, you probably have a syntax with your quotes

Comment: replace with this echo `echo('<input type="button" id="submit_addon" name="submit_addon" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'forms\')">');`

Answer (score 2):

use \'

```
echo('<input type="button" id="submit_addon" name="submit_addon" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'forms\')">');
```

In your javascript use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
     $( "#"+id ).toggle();
 }
```

Comment: In your code you write echo("<div class='forms'>") and forms be a class, no a id.

Comment: if forms is a class.. use $( ".".id ).toggle();

Comment: Just want to clarify what you are suggesting. I should put the $("<div id=''forms".id) then continue with var e = document.getElementById(id);

Comment: You need to toggle echo(" <p id='session'>" . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </p>"); when click in the button? or toggle all lines in the div with class 'forms'?

Comment: Just one more remark: in Javascript, you have to use + instead of . So the right code is $("#" + id) instead of $("#" . id)

Comment: @skyyler nice! 
I was coding in php when I said this :p

Comment: @Monroe check this option and close question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
         e.style.display = 'none';
     else
         e.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

This Javascript function will check the **"ID"** tag of your HTML element. In your view code, you have '*forms*', but it is a **class**, **not an ID**.

To make it work, change your DIV element in your view file:

```
<div id='forms'>
```

instead of

```
<div class='forms'>
```